# Pusher Error: Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500 (Focus at 500 error)

Tags: java, jax-rs, pusher, http-status-code-500

Here is my code to subscribe private channels, and when I try to make a private subscription then i got a error message

**Pusher Error Message** : `Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500`

**Scenario:**

The subscription is in javascript in **HTML** File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher('9272f25541ab7b04fc60', {
        authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/medecube/rest/initial/pusher/auth',
         auth: {
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-Token': "12345"
            }
          } 

        });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-channel');
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
          var triggered = channel.trigger('client-myEvent', { "message": "i am pusher client" });
        });

  </script>
</head>
```

My **JAX-RS web service** in java

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/pusher/auth")
    public String processMessagesAndAuthentication( MultivaluedMap<String, String> input){
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("269783", "Pusher-key", "5bbebf61fb77dbef45bc");
        String socket_id = input.getFirst("socket_id");
        String channel_name = input.getFirst("channel_name");
        String auth = pusher.authenticate(socket_id, channel_name);
        return auth;
    }
```

**Error**

> POST http://localhost:8080/medecube/rest/initial/pusher/auth 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>
> pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500

Also at my **eclipse console** it showing different type of error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager from [Module
>   "deployment.medecube.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my question.
Actually i forget to add HttpClient maven dependency for pusher in my `pom.xml` file.So that's why pusher is failed to load resource.By adding the maven dependency i got my response.

```
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
               <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
               <version>4.3.5</version>
           </dependency>
```